# $(TargetPath) for WiX project is incorrect for the post-build event

Tags: wix, windows-installer, visual-studio-2022

I'm using `$(TargetPath)` for post-build event for my WiX installer, that is built under VS 2022, and it is translated to:

```
C:\projects\My project\Installer\installer.msi
```

when the .MSI file is created in:

```
C:\projects\My project\Installer\en-us\installer.msi
```

What is wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

The PostBuildEvent property is evaluated before any targets are executed. In your case the initial value of $(TargetPath) is expanded before the wix target is called and changes it's value. Moving your post build commands to an AfterBuild target in your csproj file will solve this issue.

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="echo $(TargetPath)" />
  </Target>
```